# javascript onchange function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown in haml view:

```
= collection_select(:vehicle_part, :service, Inventory.all, :id, :title, {}, {id: 'line_item', class: 'line_item', :onchange => "{my_function(this);}"})
```

It produces following HTML (**for those who dont know haml**)

```
<select class="line_item" id="line_item" name="vehicle_part[service]" onchange="{my_function(this);}">
  <option value="1">first line</option>
  <option value="2">second line</option>
</select>
```

And my javascript looks like:

**try 1**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( ".line_item" ).change(function() {
        console.log( "Handler for .change() called." );
    });
});
```

**try 2**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    my_function(value) {
        console.log( "Handler for .change() called." );
    });
});
```

I don't know why this is not working as everything seems fine.

Any help what i am doing wrong?

**Forgot to mention:** Does this work with bootstrap-modal? I am working in bootstrap-modal

**Solution** All I was doing wrong was not refreshing my page, how fool of me just thought that by loading modal will refresh the page.

Comment: show rendered html...

Comment: haml is bizarre, can you paste in the HTML output?

Comment: already done. please see

Comment: what do you get when you `console.log( $( ".line_item" ) )` on document ready? Also, why are you declaring something in the onchange attribute if you're using JQuery later on to bind?

Comment: The second "try" is not valid JavaScript. The first one seems ok, but why do you have an inline event handler in that case? Since you don't have a function with that name, it will just throw an error.

Comment: The first one should work. The second one though will never work since it's in a closure and your `onchange` attribute is not valid javascript

Comment: @oliakaoil i get this `[prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: ".line_item", jquery: "1.11.0", constructor: function…]` and nested objects

Comment: @karl: The attribute value looks valid to me. Are blocks not handled properly in inline event handlers?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code that works:

**html:**

```
<select class="line_item" id="line_item" name="vehicle_part"><option value="1">first line</option><option value="2">second line</option></select>
```

**javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( ".line_item" ).change(function() {
        alert("abc");
    });
});
```

Note that I have changed the console.log for a alert, it it is easier to debug.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YtN8z/2/) link.

Things that needed to be changed:

- Remove the onchange event from the HTML code
- Added the class line_item in the HTML code.
- Added an alert in the javascript in order to make the code easier to debug in JSFiddle.

Comment: The `select` already has a class line_item. You have now two `class` attributes in your example. Also, using an alert is hardly necessary. Just open the console if you want to see the output of `console.log`.

Comment: Indeed, this is a mistake. Let me correct it. However, the code is working :).

Answer (score 0):

**1. Solution to Current Issue:** (with try 2 ... but no DOM ready)

Could you change:

```
onchange="{my_function(this);}"
```

To:

```
onchange="my_function(this);"
```

And then remove the DOM ready from around the function --- otherwise your inline code (global scope) does not see the function which is in the DOM ready scope.

```
function my_function(value) {
    console.log( "Handler for .change() called." );
}
```

**You're missing the function keyword on the function definiton,**

**However,** inline JS is highly discouraged. (try 1 ... delegated)

**2. HERE's the recommended way to do it:**

```
$(function() {
   $(document).on('change', '.line_item', function() {
        console.log( 'change event fired' );
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**:  The change suggested in the `onchange` attribute, #1 above, does not make a difference as the code should still fire on change with the braces. The scope of the function should be **global.**

Comment: Why should changing the value make a difference?

Comment: What value is changed? I don't get.

Comment: You're right, it should not make a difference ... I'll update my answer.

Comment: but can you tell me how to get the selected value?

Comment: That would be `this.value` or `$(this).val()` inside the `on('change', ...` callback.

Answer (score 0):

For **first try** just remove your `onchange` attribute from `select`. Because first you told look for a `my_function` which is nowhere.

For **second try** use just write just this much javascript

```
function() {
    console.log( "Handler for .change() called." );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't now any "HAML", but it looks like your "haml" produces an event handler that is not correct.

Is it possible Try to remove

```
, :onchange => "{my_function(this);}"
```

from your HAML code, so that the resulting HTML looks like

```
<select class="line_item" id="line_item" name="vehicle_part[service]"><option value="1">first line</option>
                <option value="2">second line</option></select>
```

And stick with your first try? Keep this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".line_item").change(function() {
       console.log( "Handler for .change() called." );
    });
});
```

This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StevenLangeraert/Kqtdn/) shows what you need

Comment: yes. just will remove the onchange method. nothing else will happen to it

Answer (score 0):

There's a good bit wrong with your code, and some things that can change, simply because they can.

For one, your current function (in try 2) does not require a `document.ready` function, but it relies on inline JS (which is a no-no). Then, you also forget the `function` keyword within your `document.ready`

Let's refactor your first attempt...

First, let's toss the `onchange` attribute, and do it with only JS.
Either keep it in a `document.ready` (which I wouldn't do), or simply load the JS in after the page (usually right before `</body>`).

```
<select id="line_item">...</select>
```

...

```
$("#line_item").on("change", function() {
    // ... do stuff here ...
});
```

Simple stuff.